# Faulty response while querying for email ids in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I am searching for mail ids in my indexed documents,elasticsearch is returing faulty results. This is the query i used:

```
{
“query” : {
“match” : {
“mail” : “bill@gmail.com”
}
}
}
```

In the entire indexed documents,there is only a single document containing the value "bill@gmail.com" in the field "mail". But elasticsearch response shows many other documents,which either have "bill" or "gmail.com". Why is this happening and can somebody recommend a fix for this behaviour?.

Answer (score 1):

I think your email address might be tokenized during indexing. So instead of bill@gmail.com there are three tokens (terms): bill, gmail, com. If that is the case, try to add `"index": "not_analyzed"` to its mapping definition

or

try to use [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) as below :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "mail": "bill@gmail.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch,by default,it takes the "standard analyzer" as the default analyzer.
The "standard analyzer" breaks "bill@gmail.com" in to "bill" and "gmail.com". So what happened in your case is that when you searched for "bill@gmail.com",it shows documents matching either "bill" or "gmail.com".

Two possible solutions have been mentioned by @yogesh. Another solution which is provided by elasticsearch is the UAX Email tokeniser. This tokeniser,preserves email ids and URL links and wont break them.

You can apply the UAX Email tokeniser as follows:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localost:9200/news" -d '{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "urlAnalyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
      }
    }
  }
}'

And finally apply it on our field
curl -X PUT "http://$hostname:9200/news/public/_mapping" -d '{
  "public": {
    "properties": {
      "mail": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "urlAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Here "news" is the name of the index i have created. Replace it with yours.